# How do I substitute multiple indices into one for loop for their respective list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

Say, for example, I want to write a code that takes entries from 3 or more lists, multiplies them together, and adds them up. ie:

```
a = [1,2,3,5]
b = [12,69,5,4]
c = [7,8,9,3]

answer = 0.0
for i,j,k in a,b,c:
     answer+= i*j*k
print answer
```

such that it executes something like (1)(12)(7)+(2)(69)(8)+(3)(5)(9)+(5)(4)(3). I'm not sure why I get the error "Too many values to unpack" when the lists have more than 4 entries, and "need more than two values to unpack" when the lists have 2 entries. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Close.  Your `for` loop doesn't do that, but `for i, j, k in zip(a,b,c):` does.

Comment: I'lll give that a try @Patrick Haugh. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin `sum` function:

```
a = [1,2,3,5]
b = [12,69,5,4]
c = [7,8,9,3]
answer = sum(d*e*f for d, e, f in zip(a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because `a,b,c` creates a tuple containing each list you're providing.

It seems that `zip` would do what you expect. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

It returns a list of tuple, from the list you provide, that you can unpack in the for loop:

```
a = [1,2,3,5]
b = [12,69,5,4]
c = [7,8,9,3]

answer = 0.0
for i,j,k in zip(a,b,c):
     answer+= i*j*k
print answer
```

Which gives the answer `1383.0`

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Just another method of doing it

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import add
print reduce(add, list(chain(a,b,c)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `generator-expression` with `sum` to do this in one-line for lists of any lengths (as long as they are the same length).

```
answer = sum(a[i] * b[i] * c[i] for i in range(len(a)))
```

which gives `answer` as:

```
1383
```